# WPF: store objects inside application settings.settings file

Tags: wpf, settings.settings

I build a simple `ClipboardManager` that hold all last Copy item.
So i have this simple `ClipboardItem` class:

```
public class ClipboardItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text { get; set; }
    private int _index { get; set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set
        {
            _index = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And my `ViewModel` class that hold `ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem>`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> _clipboards;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        if (_clipboards == null)
        {
            _clipboards = new ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem>();
            _clipboards.CollectionChanged += _clipboards_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void _clipboards_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _clipboards.Count; i++)
            _clipboards[i].Index = i + 1;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> Clipboards
    {
        get { return _clipboards; }
        set
        {
            _clipboards = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

So every `Copy` create new `ClipboardItem` object  inside list but when i restart the application all the records gone so i wonder if there any way to store all my `ClipboardItem` object inside the application settings.settings file.

Comment: You could write a xml file instead of Application Setting. Application Setting is for application configuration.  Save the list item in the xml file and when the application starts pump the data to the list

Comment: Any good tutorial ?

Comment: will develop a sample and provide code as answer. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

//Variable Creation

```
    private string _dataFileName = @"ClipData.xml";
    DataTable _clipDataTable = new DataTable();
```

Inside ViewModel constructor.

```
public ViewModel()
{
    if (_clipboards == null)
    {
        _clipboards = new ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem>();
        _clipboards.CollectionChanged += _clipboards_CollectionChanged;

    }

        InitDataTable();
        ReadDataFile();
}
```

Create new Methods

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Initialize Data Table considering you have only 1 column data.
    /// If you have more then you need to create more columns
    /// </summary>
    private void InitDataTable()
    {
        _clipDataTable = new DataTable();
        _clipDataTable.Columns.Add("ClipHeader");
        _clipDataTable.AcceptChanges();
    }

    //the clipboard Data is saved in xml file.
    private void WriteDataFile()
    {
        DataSet ClipDataSet = new DataSet();
        ClipDataSet.Tables.Add(_clipDataTable);
        ClipDataSet.WriteXml(_dataFileName);
    }

   // if file exits then read the xml file and add it to the Collection, which will be reflected in UI.
    private void ReadDataFile()
    {
        DataSet ClipDataSet = new DataSet();
        if (File.Exists(_dataFileName))
        {
            ClipDataSet.ReadXml(_dataFileName);

            foreach (DataRow item in ClipDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Clipboards.Add(new ClipboardItem { Text = Convert.ToString(item["ClipHeader"]) });
            }
        }
    }
```

Using Command you can bind Method of ViewModel to Window Closing event. So whenever the user closes the window, the data in the collection will be written into the Xml file.

Data from the Collection is copied into DataTable.

```
    private void WindowCloseCommadn(object o)
    {
        foreach (var item in Clipboards)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = _clipDataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["ClipHeader"] = item.Text;
            _clipDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        WriteDataFile();
    }
```

Update:-

Same Code without ViewModel, by making the codebehind class has the DataContext for binding Collection.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private ClipboardMonitor clipboardMonitor;
    private string _dataFileName = @"ClipData.xml";
    DataTable _clipDataTable = new DataTable();
    public ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem> Clipboards { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Clipboards = new ObservableCollection<ClipboardItem>();
        Clipboards.CollectionChanged += Clipboards_CollectionChanged;

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        InitiateClipboardMonitor();
        this.Closing += MainWindow_Closing1;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Closing1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in Clipboards)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = _clipDataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["ClipHeader"] = item.Text;
            _clipDataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        WriteDataFile();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitDataTable();
        ReadDataFile();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize Data Table considering you have only 1 column data.
    /// If you have more then you need to create more columns
    /// </summary>
    private void InitDataTable()
    {
        _clipDataTable = new DataTable();
        _clipDataTable.Columns.Add("ClipHeader");
        _clipDataTable.AcceptChanges();
    }

    private void WriteDataFile()
    {
        DataSet ClipDataSet = new DataSet();
        ClipDataSet.Tables.Add(_clipDataTable);
        ClipDataSet.WriteXml(_dataFileName);
    }

    private void ReadDataFile()
    {
        DataSet ClipDataSet = new DataSet();
        if (File.Exists(_dataFileName))
        {
            ClipDataSet.ReadXml(_dataFileName);

            foreach (DataRow item in ClipDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Clipboards.Add(new ClipboardItem { Text = Convert.ToString(item["ClipHeader"]) });
            }
        }
    }

    private void Clipboards_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Clipboards.Count; i++)
        {
            Clipboards[i].Index = i + 1;
        }
    }

    private void InitiateClipboardMonitor()
    {
        clipboardMonitor = new ClipboardMonitor();
        clipboardMonitor.OnClipboardContentChanged += ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged; ;
    }

    private void ClipboardMonitor_OnClipboardContentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clipboardText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
        Clipboards.Add(new ClipboardItem { Text = clipboardText });
    }
}
```

to know about Command, refer the article

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM

Comment: @user979033 let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Whats this DataTable object ? why i need it ?

Comment: DataTable,  Represents one table of in-memory data. I have chosen a simplest method to save data to xml. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: this is instead of my ListView ?

Comment: No no, DataTable is something like, List. Only difference, we can associate a type.class in List, but DataTable is like a table in Excel. It is a DataSource

Comment: So what about my ListView with the itemsource ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186066/discussion-between-satish-pai-and-user979033).

Comment: Clipboards is already bidden with itemSource of ListView right

Comment: Did you succeed ?